# Creating a Gnosis Safe Proxy on a L2

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am deploying a gnosis safe on a L2 and I tried using safe-cli https://github.com/gnosis/safe-cli (using verified factory contracts) and also using https://dev.gnosis-safe.io/.

On both occurrences the resulting proxy address from calling SafeSetup returned by ProxyCreation was a contract with very little ByteCode that I couldn't get verified, could not interact with it through safe-cli and it was not recognized in https://dev.gnosis-safe.io/.

Is this the expected outcome or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The deployed code is used the code for the proxy contract which is kept as small as possible to minimize deployment costs. If you use the official ProxyFactory at `0xa6b71e26c5e0845f74c812102ca7114b6a896ab2` the expected bytedcode (queried via `eth_getCode`) should be

> 0x608060405273ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff600054167fa619486e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060003514156050578060005260206000f35b3660008037600080366000845af43d6000803e60008114156070573d6000fd5b3d6000f3fea2646970667358221220d1429297349653a4918076d650332de1a1068c5f3e07c5c82360c277770b955264736f6c63430007060033

The code that needs to be used to verify this can be found in the [GnosisSafeProxy in the safe-contracts](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/v1.3.0-libs.0/contracts/proxies/GnosisSafeProxy.sol) repository.

An example for this can be seen on Rinkeby: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xfebb1f3f0169dc5cf23e0e3294cdac18568d8031#code

If you have a specific address that is not working for you it would be helpful to share it for further investigation.

**General comments on the Safe addresses:**

You can see the available Safe related deployments in the [safe-deployments](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-deployments/tree/main/src/assets) repository.

The `dev` version of the Safe will always deploy the complete set of Safe contracts and therefore you will get a different address.

For the `safe-cli` you should double check on the addresses with the `safe-deployment` according to the [docs](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-cli#use-custom-contracts).